# timeoutlen in vim is getting set to 500 automatically

Tags: vim

I've put following line in my .vimrc file :

```
set timeout 
set timeoutlen=2000 
set ttimeoutlen=100
```

Yet output of 
`:set timeoutlen?` is 500. What could be the cause of this? 
Is it possible that one of the plugins I've installed is resetting the value? I've installed nerdtree, nerdtree-tabs, nerdcommentor and supertab plugins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check whether plugins interfere with your setting by doing

```
verbose set timeoutlen?
```

. It should tell you something like

```
timeoutlen=500
    Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

. If it tells you exactly the same information (i.e. that it was set in the vimrc), check vimrc for setting `timeoutlen` and `tm` (latter is a short name of `timeoutlen`). It may also be set in a modeline (line at the start or end of the file, applicable only if you open one), in this case vim will say “Last set from modeline”.

Comment: Perfect! I din't know that `tm` is short for `timeout`. Some portion of vimrc that I had borrowed from somewhere was resetting `tm`. Thanks :)